# Documentation Generation from C# code for particular classes

Tags: c#

## Summary

I am looking for a piece of software that can create a html and/or PDF document from XML comments in C# code.

**I need it to only extract the public properties from classes that are inherited from a particular class.**

The tool needs to run on Windows and be free of charge.

## Example Use Case

I have a series of services that are written in C#. Each service is a class that inherits from a base service class.

Different services can be combined together using an XML document. Each service has public properties in it which are set in this XML document.

I am looking to generate a document which shows each of these services and properties that can be set for it.

### Example Source Code

I wish to generate the documentation from source code similar to this.

```
/// <summary>
/// IO service to work with Lpt port
/// </summary>
public class LptPort : Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Poll interval in ms
    /// </summary>
    /// Default: 25ms
    public int PollInterval { get; set; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/171/6834

Comment: This is different to the above question as I need software that only generates documentation for particular classes and not just for everything in the project.

Comment: The answers there should also apply. Especially Doxygen, which you can configure to only document the public classes

Answer (score 0):

You have two clear possibilities that I can recommend:

- [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/)

Both should work, are highly customisable, free and cross-platform.  Both can extract information from source code written in a multitude of languages.